# Exception thrown at 0x7B37FF80 (ucrtbased.dll) in Class 12.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00B64F88. occurred

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to c++. I am using the Visual Studio IDE. I am learning how to send objects to files and how to retreive them. While retrieving so i get an Exception at that place. I don't know what to do

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class Entity 
{
public:
    int ID;
    const char* name;

    Entity(): ID(-1), name("NOT ASSIGNED") {}
    Entity(int a, const char* b) : ID(a), name(b) {}
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Entity &e) 
{
    stream << e.ID << " " << e.name << std::endl; //exception is thrown here
    return stream;
}

void WriteToFile(Entity e)
{
    std::cout << "Writing to file\n";
    std::ofstream fout("ENTITY.txt", std::ios::app|std::ios::binary);
    fout.write((char*)&e, sizeof(e));
    fout.close();
}

void ReadFromFile()
{
    std::ifstream fin("ENTITY.txt", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        Entity a;
        fin.read((char*)&a, sizeof(a));
        std::cout << a;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Entity a(1, "A");
    Entity b(15, "C");
    Entity x;

    WriteToFile(a);
    WriteToFile(b);
    WriteToFile(x);
    ReadFromFile();
}
```

Comment: Is the resulting file content as expected? In any case, as a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you are learning from but it isn't very good if it doesn't tell you that `istream::read` and `ostream::write` cannot be used for objects such as `Entity`.

In order to work with `read` and `write` an object must be a *POD type*, POD stands for *plain old data*. Additionally anything with a pointer isn't going to work (because `write` will write the pointer itself, not what the pointer is pointing at, and the pointer value is unlikely to be valid when read again by `read`).

What you are trying to do is called serialization, and it's more complex in C++ than in some other languages. Because of this you should probably look at a serialization library. For instance [boost serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html)